# Master List of ML algorithms by type

Tags: machine-learning, references

I was asked today if there was a master list of machine learning algorithms broken down by type. I searched for one, but didn't find a good list. I was going to write one for my friend, but decided I would ask here first if someone has a good reference for a list like this. I didn't just want to direct him to Andrew Ng's videos.

Answer (score 1):

There are just incredibly many algorithms.

Here is a long list of (mostly) unsupervised algorithms:

https://elki-project.github.io/algorithms/

But of course there are still **thousands more** that are published but nobody ever used them.